# Parameter CV in grid search

Tags: python, scikit-learn

Who can tell me the difference between A and B?

```
A =kfold = KFold(n_splits=5)
grid = GridSearchCV(SVC(), parameters, cv=kfold, scoring='accuracy')

B= GridSearchCV(svc, parameters, cv=cv, scoring='accuracy', n_jobs=cpu_num)
```

Comment: in case B , the type of cv is int and you can ignore n_jobs. but in the case A, cv=Kford . I don't know the difference between intCV and kfordCV

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will assume that in case B the value of cv is 5.

As you stated in the sklearn documentation:

> Determines the cross-validation splitting strategy. Possible inputs for cv are:
>
> - None, to use the default 3-fold cross validation,
> - integer, to specify the number of folds in a (Stratified)KFold,
> - CV splitter,
> - An iterable yielding (train, test) splits as arrays of indices.
>
> For integer/None inputs, if the estimator is a classifier and y is either binary or multiclass, StratifiedKFold is used. In all other cases, KFold is used.

Therefore, in your case the question should be what is the difference between StratifiedKFold and KFold. Good explanation can be found [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/49540/understanding-stratified-cross-validation) but to summarize when StratifiedKFold is used each fold contains approximately the same percentage of samples of each target class as the complete set. This is especially useful when you have a data set with highly imbalanced classes.

If your question was about the n_jobs parameter then it simply refers to 'Number of jobs to run in parallel' -it can decrease time you need to find the best parameters as it allows to fit classifier on different folds in parallel.

Comment: I still don't understand the difference between intcv and kfordcv.Is there a difference in partitioning the data?   
What do I choose when my data are balanced dichotomies?  
What do I choose when I have data for balanced multi-classification?  
What do I choose when my data are unbalanced dichotomies?  
What do I choose when I have data for unbalanced multiple categories?  
Thank you very much

Comment: For classifiers (as in your case) If you pass an int `k` it is the same as if you passed `StratifiedKFold(n_splits=k)`. If you use StratifiedKFold` then in all folds number of instances of given class is in terms of percentage similar to the percentage in the whole data set. In general `StratifiedKFold` is a better scheme then `KFold`, so in most cases it is recommended to use it, so either use int or StratifiedKFold` object